# I'm creating a magic 8-ball application and I can't remember how to get the code looping

Tags: javascript

I'm making a magic 8-ball app, and I'm just working on the functionality as of now before I start on the graphics. I have pretty much everything working so far, I'm just having some issues on how to get the code looping. I'm pretty sure I have to use a loop, but I'm not sure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Magic 8 Ball</title>
</head>


<body>
<div id = "output">Ask a question</div>
<button id = "getResponse">Ask a question</button>

<script>
var output = document.querySelector("#output");

var getResponse = document.querySelector("#getResponse");
getResponse.style.cursor = "pointer";
getResponse.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);

var randomOutput = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);


var responses = ["It is certain.", "Without a doubt!", "Yes, definitely.", "Absolutely not. Ridiculous.", "No. How dare you.", "You may rely on it.", "No. Watch your back now, buddy.", "As I see it, yes.", "Most likely.", "Outlook good.", "Yes.", "This is a terrible question. Ask another.", "Signs point to yes.", "You should be ashamed of yourself.", "Reply hazy. Try again.", "Ask again later.", "Better not tell you now.", "How about this -- trust your intuition!", "Ask again later.", "Cannot predict now. They're listening.", "Concentrate and ask again.", "Don't count on it, worthless human.", "My reply is no.", "Never. Awful. I hate you.", "Veeeeery doubtful."];

function clickHandler ()
{
output.innerHTML = responses[randomOutput]; 
}



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button, I get a response, but when I click it again after that, it doesn't generate a response.

Comment: When you click on the button, only the code in your `clickHandler()` function is run. All the code above it is only run when the file is loaded. This means that the `randomOutput` variable is only set in the beginning, and it is not getting updated.

Answer (score 2):

Place your random output inside the `clickHandler` function like so:

```
function clickHandler ()
{
    output.innerHTML = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]; 
}
```

A better way to do this is to use the length of the array as your random max value. Then you'll be able to expand your array without changing your code every single time:

```
function clickHandler ()
{
    output.innerHTML = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)]; 
}
```

```js
var output = document.querySelector("#output");

var getResponse = document.querySelector("#getResponse");
getResponse.style.cursor = "pointer";
getResponse.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);

var randomOutput = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);


var responses = ["It is certain.", "Without a doubt!", "Yes, definitely.", "Absolutely not. Ridiculous.", "No. How dare you.", "You may rely on it.", "No. Watch your back now, buddy.", "As I see it, yes.", "Most likely.", "Outlook good.", "Yes.", "This is a terrible question. Ask another.", "Signs point to yes.", "You should be ashamed of yourself.", "Reply hazy. Try again.", "Ask again later.", "Better not tell you now.", "How about this -- trust your intuition!", "Ask again later.", "Cannot predict now. They're listening.", "Concentrate and ask again.", "Don't count on it, worthless human.", "My reply is no.", "Never. Awful. I hate you.", "Veeeeery doubtful."];

function clickHandler ()
{
output.innerHTML = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Magic 8 Ball</title>
</head>


<body>
<div id = "output">Ask a question</div>
<button id = "getResponse">Ask a question</button>


</body>
</html>
```